# Não está passando o id via get

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

Quando vou **excluir**, estou passando o `id` da tabela para exclusão.. Mas não está passando. Primeiramente coloco a confirmação de exclusão com janela MODAL.

Na URL está assim:

```
http://www.essence.com.br/model/patient-delete.php?id=
```

Ele deveria contar o número do ID..

```
<a href='../model/patient-delete.php?id='<?php echo $id['id_paciente']?>  
  data-confirm='Tem certeza de que deseja excluir o item selecionado?' 
  class = "btn btn-danger btn-xs">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Excluir
</a>
```

Mas percebo que na URL ele não está passando o `id` para patient-delete-form.
A janela modal está chamando, mas quando confirmo, não passa

Comment: Sua pergunta está um pouco vaga. Precisamos de mais detalhes para conseguir ajudar: trecho de código, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que seu problema é que você colocou o valor do `id` fora da string da url, olhe o exemplo abaixo

```php
//<a href='../model/patient-delete.php?id='<?php echo $id['id_paciente']?>
//                                        ^
//                                        a string da url terminou aqui

<a href='../model/patient-delete.php?id=<?php echo $id['id_paciente']?>'
//                                                                     ^
//                                    agora esta dentro da string da url
```

Comment: Ok, agora funcionou, obrigado